# Colored Box-shadow/Drop-shadow around a TextView?

Tags: android

I want to draw a red shadow around a TextView in Android. [image]

As in the above image. Any idea?

Comment: @pskink Okay, I am not accepting it as the answer. But I don't understand how I can achieve the result with `NinePatchDrawable`!

Comment: @pskink Sorry for not responding to you. Thanks for giving your valuable time for me. I will try this out.